# JQuery - Calling function after image load

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, deferred

So I have two functions. One to load the image and the other to resize its container element. Naturally the image element needs to be loaded, before any measurements can be taken. It looks something like this:

```
var imgEl;

loadImage(imgSrc);
// only call the below, once the above has finished loading and appending the image.
resizeModal();

function loadImage(imgSrc) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = imgSrc;
    image.onload = function() {
        imgEl = $('<img src='+image.src+'/>');
        imgEl.prependTo(modal); 
    }
}

function resizeModal() {

    // Do stuff based off the imgEl once it's been loaded and appended 
    var width = imgEl.width();
    modal.width(width)

}
```

I've tried using $.Deferred, but I'm apparently missing something, as "B" always gets logged before "A":

```
var imgEl;

loadImage(imgSrc).done( resizeModal() )

function loadImage(imgSrc) {

    var def = $.Deferred();

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = imgSrc;
    image.onload = function() {
        imgEl = $('<img src='+image.src+'/>');
        imgEl.prependTo(modal); 

        console.log("A");
        def.resolve();

    }

    return def;
}

function resizeModal() {

    console.log("B");

    // Do stuff based off the imgEl once it's been loaded and appended 
    var width = imgEl.width();
    modal.width(width)

}
```

Comment: Because image takes time to load, so when you execute `resizeModal`, the image is possibly not loaded yet. So put `resizeModal()` into `image.onload`.

Comment: @fuyushimoya: That's the whole point why the OP is using promises.

Comment: @FelixKling He first tried way is not about promises, and my comment is about that its first part of code, is there any problem?

Comment: @fuyushimoya: How am I supposed to know which part you are commenting on? You just seem to have repeated what the OP already knows: *"Naturally the image element needs to be loaded, before any measurements can be taken."*

Comment: @FelixKling I don't know, and I also don't know what I suggested has any issue. And I pointed out that his `resizeModel()` call should put into `image.onload` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are explicitly calling `resizeModal` **before** the promise is resolved:

```
loadImage(imgSrc).done( resizeModal() )
```

Just like with `foo(bar())`, this will call `resizeModal` and pass its return value to `done()`.

You want to pass the function itself instead:

```
loadImage(imgSrc).done(resizeModal)
```

This basically means "call `resizeModal` once you are done".

Comment: Ah, interesting, okay. That did log "A" before "B", but that leaves me wondering - how would one parse anything into resizeModal like this?

Comment: Pass the value to `.resolve`: `def.resolve(theValueToPassAlong)`. See https://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/

Comment: This may be even more helpful, even if it is not about jQuery's promise/deferred implementation: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to accept an answer by clicking the checkmark next to it. This lets people know that your question has been solved and especially will tell future visitors *which* solution solved your problem.

Comment: @Felix This didn't actually work my purposes due to scoping, but I found the following did: `loadImage(imgSrc).done(function(){ resizeModal(foo) })`. Anyway, your answer seems to have done the job, so thanks!

Comment: Mmh, based on the example you provided, this should work just fine. However, the cleaner solution would be to simply resolve the promise with the image element: `def.resolve(imgEl)` and `function resizeModal(imgEl) { ... }`. If you need access to other data however that is not in the scope of `resizeModal` then yes, you have to provide it another way.

Answer (score -1):

```
var loadImage = function(imgSrc, callback) {
    var imgEl;
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = imgSrc;
    image.onload = function() {
        imgEl = $('<img src='+image.src+'/>');
        imgEl.prependTo(modal); 
    }
    callback(imgEl);
}

var resizeModal = function(imgEl) {
    // Do stuff based off the imgEl once it's been loaded and appended 
    var width = imgEl.width();
    modal.width(width)
    return width;  // or whatever you are trying to get from this.
}

var finalOutput = loadImage(imgSrc, resizeModal);
```

Have you tried a structure like this?

Comment: This is basically the same as the OP's first example. Did you mean to put `callback(imgEl);` *inside* the `load` callback?